# Sort Exception in DataView

Tags: c#, sorting, exception, datagridview

I have C# code and I get an Exception from it:

> "Exception in GetCurrency For Currency Code ( USD)
>   :System.ArgumentException: Find finds a row based on a Sort order, and
>   no Sort order is specified.    at
>   System.Data.Index.FindNodeByKey(Object originalKey)    at
>   System.Data.Index.FindRecordByKey(Object key)".

Please look into my code and tell me why I am getting this Exception:

```
public static DataView curInfoView= null;

public static string GetCurSymbol(string curCode)
{
    string curSymbol = string.Empty;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(curCode))
       return curSymbol;

    try
    {
        curInfoView = new DataView(curInfoDataSet.Tables[0]);

        if (curInfoView != null)
        {
            curInfoView.Sort = "CurCode Asc";                    
            int rowIndexCurrencyInfoView = curInfoView.Find(curCode_);

            if (rowIndexCurInfoView > -1)
            {
                // initialize large currecncy
                DataRowView drCurInfo = curInfoView[rowIndexCurInfoView];
                curSymbol = Convert.ToString(drCurInfo["CurSymbol"]).Trim();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        AppLog.Log("Exception in GetCurrency For Currency Code ( " + curCode_.ToString() + ") :" + ex.ToString());
    }

    return curSymbol;
}
```

Comment: The exception clearly states that the curInfoView does not have a Sort order. Are you sure you show the right code, ie the part that actually throws?? Do step into it with the debugger!!

Answer (score 0):

I think the Sort string is case sensitive so should read

```
curInfoView.Sort = "CurCode ASC";
```

(assuming the currency code column in the dataview is CurCode)

Gareth

Comment: Yes, column Name is same in both place.

Comment: Did that fix it or are you still getting the same error?

Comment: Where does curCode_ come from?

Comment: "CurCode" is the name of column , which is on Dataset Table.

Comment: No, not CurCode, curCode_ - the one with the underscore. As TaW asks, can you check that the code you've posted is correct?